# Terraform "ocasional" variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have built the following Route 53 module to create a weighted record along with healthcheck:

```
resource "aws_route53_health_check" "health_check" {
  for_each              = var.weighted-records
  ip_address            = each.value.ip_address
  fqdn                  = each.value.fqdn
  port                  = each.value.port
  type                  = each.value.type
  resource_path         = each.value.resource_path
  failure_threshold     = each.value.failure_threshold
  request_interval      = each.value.request_interval
  search_string         = each.value.search_string
  measure_latency       = each.value.measure_latency
  invert_healthcheck    = each.value.invert_healthcheck

  tags = {
    Name = format("chk-%s", each.value.name)
  }
}
resource "aws_route53_record" "weighted_record" {
  for_each        = var.weighted-records
  zone_id         = each.value.zone_id
  name            = each.value.dns_name
  type            = each.value.dns_type
  ttl             = each.value.ttl
  health_check_id = aws_route53_health_check.health_check[each.key].id

  weighted_routing_policy {
    weight = each.value.weight
  }

  set_identifier = each.value.name
  records        = [each.value.ip_address]
}
```

In most cases, my Health check IP is the same as the destination IP, so I use the same VAR: each.value.ip_address.
However, in some cases, I need to specify a different IP for a health check.
Is there a way to avoid introducing a new VAR for health check IP and put it in every record I build? I would like to have the VAR specified only if required.

I was hoping to use either "dynamic" or "try" functions.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "optional" keyword, not "dynamic"

Answer (score 0):

Usually you specify optimal variables, by creating some default value for them:

```
variable "new_ip" {
   default = ""
}
```

Then you check if the `new_ip` was provided or not:

```
ip_address  = var.new_ip != "" ? var.new_ip : each.value.ip_address
```

Comment: Thank you! This would be helpful, but in my case default value is not going to help, since every wide-ip I build will have different values=

Comment: @viper7374 Your question does not provide any examples of those "wide-ip" and what that it even means. Thus if you can't provide important information in the question, any answers you will get will be based on what is actually in the question. Not based on those "wide-ip"s that are never mentioned, explained, showed nor exemplified.